# Adding + text before the @ in an email

Tags: email

I know with gmail you can have people email you at your email with a +sometext appended to the end of your email and you will receive the email as if it were sent to your normal email. For example, if your email is:

```
joeshmo@gmail.com
```

I can email

```
joeshmo+hello@gmail.com
```

and joeshmo@gmail.com will receive the email.

Is this a standard for email or only a feature of a few email clients? I'm writing a script that signs up users for an account on a website, and I want that script to work for users who already have an account on said website. My plan is to sign them up with

```
theiremail+mypersonaltag@theirdomain.com
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's a feature of some email _servers_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a defacto standard that has been around for at least 25 years. However while most email systems will honor the user+tag convention, I am not aware of any RFC that dictates they must honor it.

On the other hand, I'm not aware of any email system where this doesn't work. I'm sure there are some.

Comment: Outlook.com supports it, but I don't think AOL or Yahoo do.

Comment: Ouch - if it doesn't work for Yahoo or AOL I don't think my workaround is going to cut it :(

Comment: in gmail i am receiving `Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:` but i can see my email in inbox

Answer (score 3):

Qmail uses the negative sign instead of + to similar effect.

Meetup blocks the + sign all together, stating their reasoning as spam control.. https://mobile.twitter.com/meetup_support/status/499291392649080832

You can read more about this in RFC822 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/ and RFC5322 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2