# How to replace all the dots before @ in an email with empty string in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to replace all the `dots` **before** `@`  in an email with `empty string` in oracle query

like:

```
anurag.mart@hotmail.com >> anuragmart@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how this site works!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but be warned that [only Google ignores periods in the local part of an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865869/do-all-email-providers-ignore-periods-in-front-of).  Hotmail probably treats `anurag.mart@hotmail.com` and `anuragmart@hotmail.com` as different addresses, and per the RFC they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Instr - To identify the position(`@`)
- Substr - To extract data between start(`1`) and end(`@`) position
- Replace - To replace `.` with `''`
- || - To concatenate two strings

Try this

```
SELECT Replace(Substr('anurag.mart@hotmail.com', 1, 
                      Instr('anurag.mart@hotmail.com', '@', 1)), '.', '') 
       || Substr('anurag.mart@hotmail.com', Instr('anurag.mart@hotmail.com','@')+1) 
FROM   dual
```

**Result:**

```
anuragmart@hotmail.com
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/5105)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use **REGEXP_REPLACE** to identify the pattern and replace it with required pattern.

```
regexp_replace('anurag.mart@hotmail.com', '(\w+)\.(\w+)(@+)', '\1\2\3')
```

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT 'anurag.mart@hotmail.com' email_id,
  2  regexp_replace('anurag.mart@hotmail.com', '(\w+)\.(\w+)(@+)', '\1\2\3') new_email_id
  3  FROM dual;

EMAIL_ID                NEW_EMAIL_ID
----------------------- ----------------------
anurag.mart@hotmail.com anuragmart@hotmail.com
```

Comment: This code will not work for long emails such as `Mohammad.bin.Salman.Al.Saud@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

I came on this page while looking for solutions for SQL servers, I converted the above for SQL server for my project, Here is SQL if anybody else needs it.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        REPLACE(
            SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, 1, CHARINDEX('@', EmailAddress)-1),
            '.',
            ''
        ), 
        SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, CHARINDEX('@', EmailAddress), LEN(EmailAddress)) 
    )
FROM [Applicant]
```